# Specific arguments for moral realism

Tags: ethics

I'm having great difficulty so far getting specific arguments for this position. Thus far what I've found are arguments that every other position is flawed and thus false. I'm looking for some that are more specifically *for* it however. Links to resources or brief summaries are welcome. This is for my own interest, not formal education.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arguments for moral realism?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/16172/arguments-for-moral-realism)

Comment: I read it, but that wasn't very specific.

Comment: Then you'll have to be more specific as to what "specific" means. If you want them at more length this is a wrong place to ask, but online encyclopedias have long articles on moral realism, e.g. [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/moral-realism) and [IEP](http://www.iep.utm.edu/moralrea).

Comment: Okay well I've been unable to pin what the exact arguments for moral realism in fact are.

Comment: Virmaior's answer in the duplicate thread identifies three primary non-theistic arguments (MIll's, Aristotle's and Kant's) explicitly, the theistic argument is of course that what God commands (morality) is plenty real. Habit and tradition are another "argument", perhaps the most influential in practice.

Comment: I didn't see any arguments for accepting the ethics which they proposed however. As for habit and tradition, that won't fly.

Comment: Sorry, but we can not address what people do or do not "see". Those are the arguments, whether they convince someone to accept something is a personal issue that is off-topic here.

Comment: I meant that literally. As in the arguments in favor of those ethics aren't included there.